# If $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal then prove that A is skew symmetric.

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal then prove that A is skew symmetric.

I can't solve this question.

Comment: I $\LaTeX$ified your title!  If you want to see how that worked, check my edits!  Cheers!

Comment: I'm new here, so thanks for what you did :)

Comment: My pleasure!  You can learn a lot about $\LaTeX$ looking at other people's posts; just click the "edit" button and you'll see the raw textual input!  Good Luck!

Comment: @Ananya hint: Any orthogonal matrix satisfies, let's say **U** $$UU^{T}=I$$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and this is where, you can learn latex, to typeset your question/

Comment: the content should be something realted to problem what you've tries what's the context etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had no idea what to write

Comment: What is used here is MathJax, not LaTeX.  LaTeX does all sorts of stuff not involving mathematical notation.  MathJax does not.

Answer (score 4):

You know that 
$$\left((I-A)(I+A)^{-1} \right)^T(I-A)(I+A)^{-1} =I \Rightarrow \\ 
((I+A)^{-1})^{T} (I-A)^T(I-A)(I+A)^{-1} =I \Rightarrow \\
 (I-A)^T(I-A) =(I+A)^{T} (I+A)\Rightarrow \\ 
(I-A^T)(I-A) =(I+A^T)(I+A)\Rightarrow \\
I-A-A^T+AA^T =I+A+A^T+AA^T\Rightarrow \\
A+A^T=0$$

Comment: Oh my God, such a quick reply??Thank you immensely!! :)

Comment: @N. S. How about proving it's converse? That is, if $A$ is skew symmetric matrix, prove that $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal.

Comment: @Vilakshan If you know that $I+A$ is invertible then every implication above can be reversed. Note that if $A$ is real then $I+A$ is invertible, but this is not true for complex matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, it is also an eigenvector of $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\displaystyle\frac{1-\lambda}{1+\lambda}$. Noting that the eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices are either 1 or -1, we have that $\lambda$ must be 0. Since $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal, it's diagonalizable and its eigenvectors form a basis, so $A$ is diagonalizable as well. So $A=0$ and is skew symmetric.

Comment: I dont know about eigenvalues ..um.But thanks for the response :)